# How to create a link-to drop-down in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I have an application where we'd like to use a `<select>` element to control which object is loaded in a detail route.

If this were a normal `<ul>`, like if I were using bootstrap's drop-down, using the `#link-to` helper would be perfect here, because I could use the `active` class to always automatically select the item that is loaded in the child route.

With a `select` element it's a little different.  I'll probably need to write a view, I'm okay with that, but it occurs to me that parents aren't supposed to know about their children in ember, so how does a parent view get access to know which child view is currently selected?

Even a link to how the `link-to` helper is implemented could be helpful here.

Thanks!

Comment: A JSbin would help to illustrate what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm interpreting this correctly, you're looking to change the URL when the `<select>` option changes.

With a combination of `transitionToRoute`, `observes`, and `currentPath` you can achieve this using the built in [Ember.Select](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html) view class.

Here's a JSbin that might help:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jogadudase/2/edit

Comment: I actually have done something similar to this, but this does NOT support true URL routing!  If I go to `/about`, the drop-down menu still shows `/index` selected.  The tricky part here is getting the child awareness, the way a `link-to` helper knows which child route is loaded.

Comment: @DanF I've fixed this issue by using the `currentPath` property that comes with the ApplicationController. Ideally we should be able to make this a proper Component, but hopefully this helps get you started. The answer has been updated with a new JSbin link.

Comment: Yeah, that does it.  I was trying to avoid needing a reference to the application controller, but this gets the job done.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> parents aren't supposed to know about their children in ember

Where does this come from?

I'm not 100% sure of what you want to accomplish, but you probably want to use one of this: `Ember.ArrayController` or `Ember.CollectionView`.

With either of those you **can** have control over children objects.

Comment: If you `needs` a child controller, that child controller does not get torn down when you navigate away from it, and so it's a source of memory leaks.  Ideally, there's another way.

I want to have a regular routing menu represented in a drop-down select box.

CollectionView might do what I want, but the question remains:  How do the items know which route is current?  Must adopt the selection from URL routing.